# Calculating L2 norm (Euclidean norm) to set of genes in time series

Tags: r

I have gene expression RNA-seq data of 9 time points (0 hour, 2 hour, ..., 16 hour). I need a plot on which x axis is time point and each data point at a certain time point represents the L2 norm (Euclidean norm) of the difference between the gene expression vector at that time point and the previous time point.

This is the link of my expression data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1crJSqVdGujy1tFyeoV6E7e-xO9SXteJZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read your matrix into R and saved it as `m`:

```r
diffMatrix = m[,2:9] - m[,1:8]  # The change per-timepoint
l2n = apply(diffMatrix, 2, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))  # The L2-norm
```

R also has a `norm()` function, which can directly produce the L2-norm, but it turns out that [this is slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933945/how-to-calculate-the-euclidean-norm-of-a-vector-in-r) than the simple method shown here. If you click through to the other question you can find somewhat faster implementations of this, but anything will suffice for small datasets like yours.

Comment: Sorry, How can I normalise these 8 points to zero time point?     12n= Named num [1:8] 313698 168553 360237 487963

Comment: That depends entirely on how you want the normalization done.

Comment: Sorry I mean how I can normalize these 9 differences you helped me to calulate  to expression at 0 h, which corresponds to cells growing in ground state conditions?? Because they are very big and I can not plot them

Comment: You wouldn't, it doesn't make sense to normalize a difference between two time points to a third one. You could normalize everything before subtraction though.

Comment: Right, actually the goal was showing global gene expression dynamics as measured by bulk RNA-seq. I was going to plot a data point at a certain time point represents the 2-norm of the difference between the gene expression vector at that time point and the previous time point. However these differences are too big to be plotted. Thank you

Comment: Try something like plotting log2(TPM) in violin or joy plots. If there are changes in the distribution of expressed genes over time then that should make it apparent.